# Raspberry PI is not booting

Tags: boot, i2c, config.txt

I tried to follow this tutorial https://www.laub-home.de/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_multiple_I2C_bus to connect a second i2C device on GPIO-pin 17 and 27.

I had to reboot the pi after editing the /boot/config.txt file. Now my PI isn‘t booting anymore.

What can I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: undo the edits ..

Comment: Place the micro sd card in another computer, edit the \boot\config.txt file to undo your edits, replace in Pi and power on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the SD-Card in another Computer and deleted the additional line. Now my PI is booting again. Thanks!